# Change delimiter in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata

I'm an Apache Spark newbie, and I want to be able to read an XML file and count the amount of words per title. The XML file looks like this:

```
<title>first title</title>
<words>there are seven words in this example</words>
<title>second title</title>
<words>there are more words here, ten words to be precise</words>
```

I'm using Python to write the Spark job, but when I type

```
sc.textFile("file://...")
```

It automatically splits my file using the line break (\n) as its delimiter. I'd like it to split using several lines, until it finds " < title > " again.

The result I'd like to obtain would be something like:

```
first title: 7
second title: 10
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408558/how-to-handle-multi-line-rows-in-spark/46410029#46410029

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give a try to [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) if you work with XML files.