# Parse CSV file in Scala

Tags: scala, csv

I am trying to load a CSV file that has Japanese characters into a dataframe in scala. When I read a column value as `"セキュリティ対策ウェビナー開催中】受講登録でスグに役立つ「e-Book」を進呈!"` which is supposed to go in one column only, it breaks the string at `"」"`(considers this as new line) and creates two records. 
I have set the "charset" property to UTF-16 also, quote character is "\"", still it showing more records than the file.

```
val df = spark.read.option("sep", "\t").option("header", "true").option("charset","UTF-16").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("file.txt")
```

Any pointer on how to solve this would be very helpful.

Comment: I was able to read the same file without any issues in u-sql with unicode encoding which is UTF-16 only. [u-sql link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/operators/extractors/extractor-parameters#encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a new line character in your Japanese string. Can you try using the multiLine option while reading the file?

```
var data = spark.read.format("csv")
 .option("header","true")
 .option("delimiter", "\n")
 .option("charset", "utf-16")
 .option("inferSchema", "true")
 .option("multiLine", true)
 .load(filePath)
```

Note: As per the below answer there are some concerns with this approach when the input file is very big.
[How to handle multi line rows in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408558/how-to-handle-multi-line-rows-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work for UTF-16. I couldn't able to set csv file encoding UTF-16 in Notepad++ and hence I have tested it with UTF-8. Please make sure that you have set input file encoding which is UTF-16.

Code snippet :

```
val br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream("C:/Users/../Desktop/csvFile.csv"), "UTF-16"));

  for(line <- br.readLine()){
    print(line)
  }

  br.close();
```

csvFile content used:

```
【セキュリティ対策ウェビナー開催中】受講登録でスグに役立つ「e-Book」を進呈!,January, セキュリティ, 開催, 1000.00
```

**Update:**

If you want to load using spark then you can load csv file as below.

```
spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("charset", "UTF-16")
      .option("header", "false")
      .option("escape", "\\")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .load(fromPath)
```

Sample Input file for above code:

```
  "102","03","セキュリティ対策ウェビナー開催中】受講登録でスグに役立つ「e-Book」を進呈!","ｶｸﾞﾗｱｶｶﾞﾜﾔﾂｷﾖｸ","セキュリティ","受講登録でス"
```

Comment: I am getting the count mismatch while loading the data into a dataframe. I have edited the question with the code. Do I need to put any other filter?

Comment: Please refer my updated comment. Hope it will help!

Comment: If it doesn't work updated code then please share your sample csv file.