# Reading a multiline CSV file in Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am trying to read a multiline csv file in spark. My schema is: Id, name and mark.
My input and actual output are given below. I am not getting the expected output. Can someone please help what I am missing in my code.

**Code:**

```
val myMarkDF =   spark
                .read
                .format("csv")
                .option("path","mypath\\marks.csv")
                .option("inferSchema","true")
                .option("multiLine","true")
                .option("delimiter",",")
                .load
```

**Input:**

```
1,A,
97,,
1,A,98
1,A,
99,,
2,B,100
2,B,95
```

**Actual output:**

```
+---+----+----+
|_c0| _c1| _c2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   A|null|
| 97|null|null|
|  1|   A|  98|
|  1|   A|null|
| 99|null|null|
|  2|   B| 100|
|  2|   B|  95|
+---+----+----+
```

**Expected output:**

```
+---+----+----+
|_c0| _c1| _c2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   A|  97|
|  1|   A|  98|
|  1|   A|  99|
|  2|   B| 100|
|  2|   B|  95|
+---+----+----+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need the extra option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46410545/103081)

Comment: Thanks for your looking into my question. But unfortunately, it is still not giving the expected o/p after adding the parserlib option.

Comment: It was a guess.  I have not used spark in a while.  If it becomes necessary to transform the multi-line csv to single-line outside of the reader, I would not use spark for that because adjacent lines may not both be on the same worker.  Basically, you lose adjacency in a dataframe/rdd.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I am just experimenting.

Comment: 3 questions: can the same record shown on 3 lines, can a line contains more than 1 records? your sample records are always broken at the 3rd column, can this happen on the 2nd column, for example, the first line is `1,,` and 2nd line is `A,97,`? please add all potential cases.

Comment: yes, it can be of any combos. For sampling, I have broken the records at the third column. Each record confines to this schema -> Id, name and mark.

Comment: Can any of the three columns be null or Empty? Can you add the data type of the columns?

Comment: They can not be empty. Id is of integer, name is of string and mark is of integer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: a better solution which handles more types of broken records (broken at 2nd or 3rd column). The important part is the calculation of a cumsum of non-null entries, which groups together the rows that are supposed to be in the same record.

```
val df = spark.read.csv("file.csv")
df.show
+---+----+----+
|_c0| _c1| _c2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   A|null|
| 97|null|null|
|  1|   A|  98|
|  1|null|null|   <-- note that I intentionally changed these two rows
|  A|  99|null|   <-- to demonstrate how to handle two types of broken records
|  2|   B| 100|
|  2|   B|  95|
+---+----+----+
```

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "id", monotonically_increasing_id()
).withColumn(
    "notnulls",
    $"_c0".isNotNull.cast("int") + $"_c1".isNotNull.cast("int") + $"_c2".isNotNull.cast("int")
).withColumn(
    "notnulls",
    ceil(sum($"notnulls").over(Window.orderBy("id")) / 3)
).groupBy("notnulls").agg(
    filter(
        flatten(collect_list(array("_c0","_c1","_c2"))),
        x => x.isNotNull
    ).alias("array")
).select(
    $"array"(0).alias("c0"),
    $"array"(1).alias("c1"),
    $"array"(2).alias("c2")
)

df2.show
+---+---+---+
| c0| c1| c2|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  A| 97|
|  1|  A| 98|
|  1|  A| 99|
|  2|  B|100|
|  2|  B| 95|
+---+---+---+
```

**Old answer which doesn't work too well:**

Not the best way to parse a csv, but at least an MVP for your use case:

```
val df = sc.wholeTextFiles("marks.csv").map(
    row => row._2.replace(",,\n", "\n").replace(",\n", ",").split("\n")
).toDF(
    "value"
).select(
    explode($"value")
).select(
    split($"col", ",").as("col")
).select(
    $"col"(0), $"col"(1), $"col"(2)
)

df.show
+------+------+------+
|col[0]|col[1]|col[2]|
+------+------+------+
|     1|     A|    97|
|     1|     A|    98|
|     1|     A|    99|
|     2|     B|   100|
|     2|     B|    95|
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks mck!,  The documentation says that If  records sprawl more than one lines in a csv file, by simply enabling the multiLine option to true, the records can be read without data loss. In my case, it is not working. Could you please help on this.

Comment: @user3103957 A record spreading across more than one line means something like `a,b,c\nd`, instead of your file format which looks like `a,b,\nc,,`. There are 2 spurious commas in your file format.

Comment: @user3103957 I've added another way to parse the dataframe - see if the edited answer helps