# Reading flat file with multi-line string without quote with PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a flat file delimited by `|` (pipe), without quote character. Sample data looks as following:

```
SOME_NUMBER|SOME_MULTILINE_STRING|SOME_STRING
23|multiline
text1|text1
24|multi
mulitline
text2|text2
25|text3|text4
```

What I'm trying to do is to load it into a dataframe to look something like this:

| SOME_NUMBER | SOME_MULTILINE_STRING | SOME_STRING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | multiline text1 | text1 |
| 24 | multi mulitline text2 | text2 |
| 25 | text3 | text4 |

I tried to specify `multiLine` option with no luck. Regardless of it being set to `True` or `False`, the output doesn't change. I suppose what I'm trying to achieve there is to specify that I'm expecting multi-line data, and every record has the same number of columns specified in the schema.

```
df_file = spark.read.csv(filePath, \
                         sep="|", \
                         header=True, \
                         enforceSchema=True, \
                         schema=df_table.schema, \ # I need to explicitly specify the schema
                         quote='', \
                         multiLine=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a multiline CSV file in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376761/reading-a-multiline-csv-file-in-spark)

Comment: @mck I don't think so. In my case, I have a multi-line string that I want to interpret as on pice. In linked question, it has more to do with the value being moved to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that type of psv (pipe-separated values) file without quotes but with multiline values (newline in cell values) you need a stateful algorithm that loops through the rows and decides when to insert the quotes. This means the operation is not easily parallelizable. So you might as well do it using python on rdd rows:

```
def from_psv_without_quotes(path, sep='|', quote='"'):
    rddFromFile = sc.textFile(path)
    rdd = rddFromFile.zipWithIndex().keys()
    
    headers = rdd.first()
    cols = headers.split(sep)
    schema = ", ".join([f"{col} STRING" for col in cols])
    n_pipes = headers.count('|')
    
    rows = rdd.collect()
    processed_rows = []
    n_pipes_in_current_row = 0
    complete_row = ""

    for row in rows:
        if n_pipes_in_current_row < n_pipes:
            complete_row += row if n_pipes_in_current_row == 0 else "\n"+row
            n_pipes_in_current_row += row.count('|')

        if  n_pipes_in_current_row == n_pipes:
            complete_row = quote + complete_row.replace('|', f'{quote}|{quote}') + quote
            processed_rows.append(complete_row)
            n_pipes_in_current_row = 0
            complete_row = ""
    
    processed_rdd = sc.parallelize(processed_rows)
    print(processed_rdd.collect())

    df = spark.read.csv(
        processed_rdd,
        sep=sep,
        quote=quote,
        ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=True,
        ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True,
        header=True,
        mode='PERMISSIVE',
        schema=schema,
        enforceSchema=False,
    )

    return df


df = from_psv_without_quotes('/path/to/unqoted_multiline.psv')
df.show()
```

I am assuming you are constrained to reading from Hadoop, so the example solution is naive first attempt. It is really inefficient because of the `rdd.collect()` etc. I am sure you could do this much more efficiently if you avoided the whole spark infrastructure and preprocessed the unquoted multiline file with some gnu tools like `sed`and `awk`.