# Handling Column breaks in pipe delimited file

Tags: python, linux, pyspark

We have a 50GB text file which is pipe delimited(|), as follows

Column1|Column2|Col
umn3|Column4|Column5

Value1|Value2|Value
3|Value4|Value5

So the challenge is while reading it into pyspark dataframe. Since each column/value is breaking into next line after a fixed width. If each column was in quotes, I could tell spark to use multiline and treat values inside them as one even when there is a line break.
How to handle in this case? Should I preprocess this file before loading to Spark?

expecting a solution to read this file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708177/3238085 the only caveat is this needs to be processed under a single executor

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dask` to achieve this task of preprocessing. The following code will process the 50GB file in blocks of 500MB and write out the output in 5 partitions. Everything is a delayed / lazy operation just like in spark. Let me know how it goes. You may have to remove the header line from the data and then provide the header in your spark dataframe.

Install dask as

`pip install dask[complete]`

```
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import delayed


def preprocess_line(line):
    processed_line = '|'.join([f'"{field}"' for field in line.split('|')])
    return processed_line


if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_file = "../data/pipedelimited.csv"

    client = Client(n_workers=8, threads_per_worker=4)
    b = db.read_text(input_file, blocksize="500MB")  # blocksize=None for streaming, read more on the options here
    line_count = b.count()
    line_count_computed = line_count.compute()
    print(f"count of lines in whole file = {line_count_computed}")

    delayed_partitions = b.to_delayed()

    first_flag = True
    first_line = None
    second_line = None
    processed_lines = []


    for delayed_partition in delayed_partitions:
        partition = delayed_partition.compute()
        lines = iter(partition)
        print(f"first line = {lines}")

        try:
            while True:
                if first_flag:
                    first_line = next(lines)
                    first_flag = False
                    continue
                else:
                    second_line = next(lines)
                    final_line = first_line + second_line.strip()
                    processedline = preprocess_line(final_line)
                    processed_lines.append(processedline)
                    #print(processedline)
                    first_flag = True

        except StopIteration:
            print("Reached the end of the list.")


    processed_bag = db.from_sequence(processed_lines, npartitions=5)

    output_path = "../dask_output/processed_corrected.csv"
    processed_bag.to_textfiles(output_path)
```

Output is as follows :

```
count of lines in whole file = 2592
first line = <list_iterator object at 0x724570f54ac0>
Reached the end of the list.
```